# getting error when i am sending mail via smtp

Tags: vb.net

```
        Dim MESSAGE As New MailMessage()
        MESSAGE.From = New MailAddress(Mail_From)
        MESSAGE.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        MESSAGE.To.Add(email)
        MESSAGE.Subject = "Testing"
        MESSAGE.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        MESSAGE.Body = msg
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Host = SMTP_Host
        smtp.Port = SMTP_Port
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(Mail_User, Mail_PW)
        smtp.EnableSsl = False
        smtp.Send(MESSAGE)
```

1. i got error:

   > MAIL  Error Message:Mailbox unavailable. The server response was:
   >   This email has  identified as high probability of being a spam mail
   >   by our

Comment: http://emailmarketing.comm100.com/email-marketing-ebook/flagged-as-spam.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The mail has been rejected by the server, there is nothing you can do to resolve this. You could in theory attempt to modify the content so that is does not appear as spammy, but this is likely to be a long and tedious process.

Comment: can you give solution for this where can i modify

Comment: There is no canned solution I can give you. You need to modify the content and/or subject and/or sender email and attempt to send the email again. The recipient server will then either accept it or reject it.

Comment: i changed subject and body message and recipient domain to hotmail but till it showing same error message

Comment: Then it could well be the IP address you are sending from. There are various factors that could affect deliverability, content being one of them. Unfortunately, only a thorough analysis of your individual circumstances would confirm what needs to change and that is not something that will happen on a site like this.

Comment: I use to get my mail rejected because I used a non-existent internal mail address donotreply@company.com as the FROM address and this caused the mail to be rejected. Once I change this to an existing mail address it worked.